# SQL Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I have created a service broker that stores id's in the queue table. But the problem is when i want to get the id back in the stored procedure it's now formatted as xml. Because the service broker message is XML.

How can i just get the last Id each time because the trigger is fired after an update of a row.

Below my code =>

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dba].[TriggerCall]    Script Date: 6/16/2015 2:55:57 PM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dba].[TriggerCall] ON  [dba].[CallID] FOR     UPDATE 
AS 

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @MessageBody XML  
    DECLARE @ID varchar(50)
    -- Insert statements for trigger here

                --get relevant information from inserted/deleted and convert to xml message  
        SET @MessageBody = (SELECT Id FROM inserted  
        FOR XML AUTO)          

                    If (@MessageBody IS NOT NULL)  
        BEGIN 

                    DECLARE @Handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;   
                    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @Handle   
                    FROM SERVICE [TestServiceInitiator]   
                    TO SERVICE 'TestServiceTarget'   
                    ON CONTRACT [TestContract]   
                    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;   
                    SEND ON CONVERSATION @Handle   
                    MESSAGE TYPE [TestMessage](@MessageBody);
        END

END



/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_GetCall]    Script Date: 6/16/2015 2:44:27 PM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetCall]
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @message_type varchar(100) 
DECLARE @dialog uniqueidentifier, @message_body XML; 
Declare @Object as Int; 
Declare @URL as varchar(255)
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @ID as Varchar(38);

WHILE (1 = 1) 
        BEGIN -- Receive the next available message from the queue 
        WAITFOR ( 
                    RECEIVE TOP(1) @message_type = message_type_name,     
                    @message_body = CAST(message_body AS XML),     
                    @dialog = conversation_handle

        FROM dbo.TestQueue ), TIMEOUT 500    if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0 OR @message_body IS NULL) 

        BEGIN 

                    BREAK 
        END 
              ELSE 
                    BEGIN 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[testtabel]
       ([id]
       ,[callid],
       [test])
 VALUES
       ('111', '111', @message_body)


                    END
        END CONVERSATION @dialog 
        END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're just looking to rehydrate the ID into an int. If that's the case, the following should do:

```
use tempdb;
create table inserted (id int);
insert into inserted values (1);
declare @message_body xml;

set @message_body= (select * from inserted for xml auto);
select @message_body.value('(/inserted/@id)[1]', 'int');
```

The magic is the last line (the rest was just setup for me to test).

I'll take this opportunity to clear up a misconception that you seem to have, though. Triggers in SQL server aren't fired per row, but per batch. So, if you run an update against your table and it updates 50 rows, the trigger gets fired once and the inserted (and deleted) table will have 50 rows in it. Just something to take into account.